# How to use slide with hide or show in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do some animation but it's not working.

Without the slide effect all works fine but when I use slide it breaks my code and the animation is not working. Am I doing something wrong?

My code:

```js
('.answer_buttons a').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
$('.selected')
  .find('input')
  .val($(this).hasClass('nu') ? 'nu' : 'da')
  .end()
  .removeClass('selected')
  .hide('slide', {
    direction: 'left'
  }, 1000)
  .nextAll('.question').first('slide', {
    direction: 'left'
  }, 1000).show().addClass('selected');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="" class="question" id="intreb_1">
  <input name="intr1" value="da" type="hidden">Intrebarea 1?</p>
<p style="display: block; overflow: hidden;" class="question" id="intreb_2">
  <input name="intr2" value="nu" type="hidden">Intrebarea 2?</p>
<p class="question " id="intreb_3">
  <input name="intr3" value="" type="hidden">Intrebarea 3?</p>
<p class="question " id="intreb_4">
  <input name="intr4" value="" type="hidden">Intrebarea 4?</p>
<p class="question  last" id="intreb_5">
  <input name="intr5" value="" type="hidden">Intrebarea 5?</p>
<div class="answer_buttons">
  <a class="nu" href=""></a>
  <a class="da" href=""></a>
```

Comment: Add HTML code also in the question

Comment: your code snippet doesn't show anything

Comment: @Tushar, I added HTML code.

Comment: Yes, you did but now the JS code is incomplete. Add complete code. When you're calling this function?

Comment: Added complete JS code.

Comment: It's not complete. You missed a `$` and you have no text in those `<a>` tags so you can't click them.

Comment: Kindly add a fully functioning demo, at least run your code before posting. Right now, there is no way to click the element on which you've bound event

Comment: When I click on yes or no I want the current question to slide to left and hide and the next on to slide from right and show. At the same time. Here is a fiddle of what am I trying to acomplish http://jsfiddle.net/9x8co7f1/3/